# Kernel Debugging: Windows 7 hangs at boot time

Tags: windows, debugging, device-driver, kernel

Sometimes, I have the situation that Windows waits at boot time for the kernel debugger to be attached. You see the text "Windows starting" but not the logo yet.

If I attach the debugger now, Windows 7's logo animation is played. Aftwards the logo starts to pulse. At this stage the boot process does not advance anymore. CPU usage drops to a minimum.
I wait usually several minutes, but nothing happens.

This does not happen all the time. However, if it happens, a VM reset won't help. I need to use startup repair to fix this problem. Unfortunately, it takes forever.

Any ideas what I can do except running startup repair ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If your VM supports snapshots, you could create a snapshot from a healthy VM and if it fails, you can revert to the snapshot.

Comment: I'm doing that already ;) , but sometimes I need to boot the VM.

Comment: You say that sometimes Windows waits at boot time until you attach the debugger - is this happening before or after the Windows Boot Manager menu appears?  (If you don't currently have the boot menu enabled, I recommend that you enable it.)

Comment: This happens is after  the boot manager appears.

Comment: OK, I suggest that the next time this happens you reset the VM without attaching the debugger, then try booting with debugging turned off.  I suspect this won't make any difference, in which case it is likely that the damage is being caused is something you are doing with the VM before the reboot.  You may want to boot to external media (Windows PE) or mount the virtual disks in your host system and see if you can figure out what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem you encountered, you just need to press F10 during boot up. And remove /debug and related parameters. Then press enter.

Suggestion:
Do not use /debug parameter for your default boot menu option. Copy your boot configuration to a new entry. Then set it to debug mode.
Windows don't know when you will use the debugger. So it has to wait.

Thanks.

Comment: You can disable it with: "bcdedit /set {default} debug off". Sometimes just doing "bcdedit /debug off" doesn't work; you can verify by doing "bcdedit" and it should say at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by leaving the mouse) inside the VM during bootup... Don't know why, but it solves the problem for me.
I'm debugging Win Embedded POSReady 7 SP1 x86 within VMware Workstation v9.0.2 on a Win7 Enterprise x64 host.